# How to open a modal dialog on CWinApp::ExitInstance()

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I wanted to show a modal dialog while doing the clean up on `ExitInstance()` then terminate the dialog after the clean up is complete.
Below is my sample code from which I created a sample app from the Visual Studio MFC project template.

```
int CMFCApplication2App::ExitInstance()
{
#if 1
  CDialog dlg(IDD_UPLOADDLG);
  dlg.DoModal();
#endif

  return CWinApp::ExitInstance();
}
```

I get this message error prompt below.

[image]

Comment: I edited to remove C++ and modal-dialog tags. Not really a C++ question and it will annoy people in the C++ forum and cause your question to be voted down. You can see my answer to you.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I suppose in `ExitInstance` too much internal cleanup has already been done by MFC. What is the dialog supposed to do? There may a better place for this dialog to be displayed. Is it a dialog based application? You need to tell us more so we can give further advice. This looks like a typical [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: In addition to not being a valid option (as explained by @JosephWillcoxson), this is also useless: your program would block until that dialog is dismissed, and no clean-up would be done.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I wanted to prevent the app to exit while waiting for the completion of the files  being uploaded. I am thinking of displaying a progress bar within a modal dialog so that it will not continue to exit the app. Yes it is a dialog based app.

Comment: @Marss that's definitely how you should do it.

Comment: @Jabberwocky the problem is ExitInstance() does not allow to display a modal dialog. it is prompting me that error message prompt. release config works fine. only in debug config

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you click "Retry" while in the debugger, it will take you to the offending line. I opened up `thrdcore.cpp` in an editor and went to line 168. A general message about calling `PumpMessage` when not allowed.

From thrdcore.cpp:

```
BOOL AFXAPI AfxInternalPumpMessage()
{
    _AFX_THREAD_STATE *pState = AfxGetThreadState();

    if (!::GetMessage(&(pState->m_msgCur), NULL, NULL, NULL))
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        TRACE(traceAppMsg, 1, "CWinThread::PumpMessage - Received WM_QUIT.\n");
            pState->m_nDisablePumpCount++; // application must die
#endif
        // Note: prevents calling message loop things in 'ExitInstance'
        // will never be decremented
        return FALSE;
    }

#ifdef _DEBUG
  if (pState->m_nDisablePumpCount != 0)
    {
      TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "Error: CWinThread::PumpMessage called when not permitted.\n");
      ASSERT(FALSE);
    }
#endif

#ifdef _DEBUG
    _AfxTraceMsg(_T("PumpMessage"), &(pState->m_msgCur));
#endif

  // process this message

    if (pState->m_msgCur.message != WM_KICKIDLE && !AfxPreTranslateMessage(&(pState->m_msgCur)))
    {
        ::TranslateMessage(&(pState->m_msgCur));
        ::DispatchMessage(&(pState->m_msgCur));
    }
  return TRUE;
}
```

It's telling you not to display a modal dialog (or do anything else that would call `PumpMessage`) during `ExitInstance()`. When `WM_QUIT` is received it increments `m_nDisablePumpCount` and then the program begins shutdown eventually calling `ExitInstance()`.

Instead, don't display this dialog. Honestly, it has no purpose. A modal dialog will block on the spot. If you want to display a useful window/prompt on shutdown, do it for the frame window's `WM_CLOSE` message.

Comment: Thank you for the response.
I am preventing the app to exit while I do something within the modal dialog class.
I can do the cleanup within the modal dialog class instead.
The exception prompt only occurs on debug config, but release config is fine.

Comment: @mar Don't fool yourself. The Release configuration isn't fine. It simply doesn't have the diagnostic code compiled into the executable, so it remains silent when you attempt to enter an unsupported application state. The bug is still there, and you should do yourself a favor and fix it.